# Some theorems of model theory

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

Do theorems like "omitting types theorem", "Extended completeness theorem" etc.. hold inside arbitrary countable transitive models of ZFC?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if they're theorems of ZFC, the answer is trivially "yes." Do you suspect they're not theorems of ZFC for some reason?

Comment: No I don't suspect they are not theorems of ZFC. Does it suffice to reproduce their proofs to convince the reader of my arguments?

Comment: You don't even have to do that. By definition, a countable transitive *model* of ZFC is, indeed, a model. This just means it satisfies all the theorems of ZFC. So if you've proved the omitting types theorem from the axioms of ZFC, then it goes without saying that these hold internal to any model of ZFC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just expanding on the comments here:

Yes. When we prove theorems in model theory, we're doing just the same sort of mathematics we do when we prove theorems in group theory or real analysis. This mathematics can be formalized in ZFC, and the theorems in model theory, just like the theorems in any other branch of math, are theorems of ZFC. Hence they hold inside any model of ZFC.

Of course, sometimes people (especially logicians) study consequences of stronger systems than ZFC. But authors are usually very careful to point out when a theorem they are proving requires extra assumptions.